# Database Schema: Complex/Best Practice vs Simplified

Tags: database, schema

I'm in a quandary over whether to go for (as I see it) best practice, or expediency.  The application I'm currently working on is underpinned by a system of "tokens" that users exchange with one another.  These tokens can be grouped together as "units" (of a fixed size).

### Original Schema

The data model I originally drew up to represent this tracked each "token" individually, and recorded each of its movements.  The result is a schema that contains numerous tables to represent each of the unique items, their histories, historical event types, units, and unit membership (including history - so each membership record tracks the entry/exit time of each token.

Whilst the original model is comprehensive, and offers a lot of scope for analysis, it makes queries (such as determining how many tokens a user has in total - factoring in history) particularly complex, because each one joins on numerous tables, and resorts to mechanisms like `COUNT()`.

### Alternative

The model can be dramatically simplified if tokens are not tracked individually.  In this scenario, the tables that track history can be collapsed into a single balance table that records a numeric value against each user (e.g. "*x* has *n* tokens").  Similarly, since movements between units do not need to be tracked within the data model, and they are always of a fixed size, they too do not need to be individually modelled, and can be generated as and when they're required (e.g. taking 2 tokens from a user's balance and calling it a unit - assuming the fixed unit size is 2).

The downside, of course, is that the ability to perform analysis is lost with the detailed tracking data.  The best solution I've been able to come up with for this is detailed application logging in a fixed format (depending on message type), which could be parsed and (if necessary) dumped into a separate database - or kept in a file and stored somewhere.

Unfortunately, the biggest caveat here is time.  The original, more detailed, model strikes me as the better from a best practice perspective (which is why I originally chose it), but the time constraints (context: startup business) have made me veer towards the simplified model + logging option.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Thanks!

EDIT: thanks to Thilo below for reminding me about scalability - another point in favour of the simplified schema (I forgot to mention it when I originally wrote the question, but disk space had been a concern of mine - once usage of application started to ramp up).

Comment: Potential middleway: Do both. Have your complex token-tracking schema (if you really need it, it might not scale too well), but also keep denormalized tallies of the current totals.

Comment: That's a good idea - we were going with logging anyway (albeit not quite as detailed), so there could be some merit in doing both.